Realm Environment Collections
How do you create a Realm environment object or collection?
@StateObject var animalGroup = AnimalGroup()
WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
        .environmentObject(animal)
}

And where will it be declared? After Login?
@ObservedResults(AnimalGroup.self) var animalGroups

Welcome to SO. There are many answers to this question but it really needs refinement and details to be correctly answered (we don't want to guess). Where is the code in the question being placed? Why do you want to inject that as an environmentObject (seems like a bad idea), it's already a state object - do you want every subview to use it? Please take a moment and review How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. What is meant by After Login? - are we to assume this is a sync'd app?
